# How do I get the formula of a function, based on values in a dataframe using pyhton

Tags: python, excel, function, dataframe, regression

I have got a draframe with x and y values. In excel you can generate the formula of the function based on your input values.
I know that the function is something like that: -ax^2+bx+c

[That would be my goal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ayLSn.png)
How can i generate the formula of the function in python?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `curve_fit` method from scipy for that: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html

It basically takes any function (e.g. your `-ax^2+bx+c`) and tries to estimate the parameters (a, b, and c) from a dataset. I don't have your data, but have a look at the examples in the scipy docs and you should be able to figure it out.

Comment: thank you, it worked!
    def func(x, a, b, c):
        return -a*x**2+b*x+c
    plt.plot(x, y, 'b-', label='data')
    popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, x, y)